# Collection similar to Document.Revisions

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using VBA in Word 2013.

In the Word object model, `Document.Revisions` gives you a collection of revision objects (tracked changes), and you can accept or reject them programmatically. Plus, the collection itself has a `Count` property.

I did not find any feature in the object model that exposes the Undo/Redo count or history. To clarify, I am looking for a way to determine how many **user** changes are in the Undo stack and the Redo stack at a given time (because I am not editing the document contents via macro). It would be a bonus to be able to see the individual changes that are available to undo or redo, but I'm okay without that.

I know I can use the `Document.Undo` and `Document.Redo` methods, but I don't see a way to get a count of changes that can be undone or a count of undone changes that can be redone.

I suppose I could just iterate through the stack, so to speak, by invoking `Document.Undo` or `.Redo` and checking the return value to see whether there was anything there, then reversing what I had just undone/redone. I was hoping for something akin to `Document.Revisions.Count`.

EDIT: I need to access the Redo stack. It begins to look as though the object model does not expose that object. An old (2013) question recorded [here](http://visual668.rssing.com/chan-11590904/all_p42.html) suggests that there is no such object/collection (search for "redorecord").

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create & deploy a custom UndoRecord, so you can roll back all your actions in one go at the end, via code like 'ActiveDocument.Undo', without the need to keep track of all the intervening edits. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/Concepts/Working-with-Word/working-with-the-undorecord-object

To deploy this for end-user actions in the document itself, simply use:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objUndo As UndoRecord

Sub CreateUndoRecord()
Set objUndo = Application.UndoRecord
objUndo.StartCustomRecord
End Sub
```

to create the Custom Record then, when you're finished, clear the lot with:

```
Sub ClearUndoRecord()
objUndo.EndCustomRecord
ActiveDocument.Undo
End Sub
```

Comment: That's fascinating. I'm not sure it meets my needs. I think I was unclear in my description, so I edited it.  From what I read about UndoRecord, it sounds like the object only records changes made by VBA. What I'm looking for is a way to access the Undo (and Redo) stacks of changes made by the user. Is that possible?

Comment: Gosh, I wish this took care of my problem. However, I still need to access the Redo stack. It begins to look as though the object model does not expose that object. See my further edit. Thanks!

Comment: There is no RedoRecord equivalent to UndoRecord in VBA or WordBasic.